# Django:TemplateDoesNotExist at /accounts/login/

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

> accounts/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms

# Create your models here.
class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True,label='email',error_messages={'exists':'This already exists'})
    firstname = forms.CharField(required=True,label='firstname')
    lastname = forms.CharField(required=True,label='lastname')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('firstname','lastname','username','email','password1','password2')
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['firstname'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'First Name'
        self.fields['lastname'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Last Name'
        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Username'
        self.fields['email'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Email'
        self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Password'
        self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Confirm Password'

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserCreateForm,self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
    
    def clean_email(self):
        if User.objects.filter(email=self.cleaned_data['email']).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError(self.fields['email'].error_messages['exists'])
        return self.cleaned_data['email']
```

> accounts/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, auth
from accounts.models import UserCreateForm
from django.http import JsonResponse
import random
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.conf import settings

def registerpage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #login
        form = UserCreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save()
            new_user = authenticate(
                username = form.cleaned_data['username'],
                password = form.cleaned_data['password1'],
            )
            login(request, new_user)
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        #registration
        form = UserCreateForm() 
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'store/auth/register.html', context)
```

> accounts/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path,include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('register', views.registerpage, name='register'),
    path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

> urls.py of parent project root folder

```
"""
URL configuration for quality-traders project.

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('store.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),

]

urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

> register.html

```
{% extends "store/layouts/main.html" %}

{% block content %}

<section id="form" style="margin-left: 25%;"><!--form-->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1 ">

            <div class="signup-form"><!--sign up form-->
                <h2>New User Signup!</h2>
                <form method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {% for field in form %}
                    {{ field.errors }}
                    <p>{{field}}</p>
                    {% endfor %}
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Signup</button><br>

                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center links">
                        Already have an account?
                        <a href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div><!--/sign up form-->

        </div>
    </div>
</section><!--/form-->

{% endblock content %}
```

> login.html

```
{% extends "store/layouts/main.html" %}

{% block content %}

<section id="form " style="margin-left: 25%;"><!--form-->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1 ">

            <div class="signup-form"><!--sign up form-->
                <h2>User Login!</h2>
                <form method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {% for field in form %}
                    {{ field.errors }}
                    <p>{{field}}</p>
                    {% endfor %}
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Login</button><br>

                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center links">
                        Already have an account?
                        <a href="{% url 'login' %}">Sign Up</a>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div><!--/sign up form-->

        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section><!--/form-->

{% endblock content %}
```

> settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

I create this ecommerce website by watching a tutorial, https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLTV1jAY3nKHOqKs4uDaBOdqL3jKK7fjSo&si=h5Hl6NapOuWZvjIa.

He created the register and login with a single view. He created the template url for only registering. Login and logout were come from,

```
path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
```

He was not using any separate app for authentication and authorisation. But I do. There the conflict happened.

I tried to implement the login and logout using,

```
path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
```

as I thought that the **accounts/** will automatically come because the urls.py is part of the accounts app.

But I got,
[TemplateDoesNotExist at /accounts/login/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8oeS.png)

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the template directory. The login.html was in **store->auth** folder inside the templates.

Django was searching it in **registration** folder of the templates.

So I created a registration folder and added the login and register templates to it.

Thank you.